# PHP - MySql : (String) put slash between 2 number

Tags: php, mysql, string, slash

I've problem in my code, I use these lines for example:

```
$numb1 = 12;
$numb2 = 6;
$folder = (string)$numb1."/".$numb2;
echo ($folder); // => 12/6
$sql="insert into test (folder) values (".$folder.");   
// Here the value of folder is "2" !!!
// Structure of the colume folder : varchar(50) utf8_general_ci
```

I went insert in this column "folder" the string output "12/6", but every time in database I get the division of `$numb1 / $numb2`, in this case I get "2";.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using mysqli. It's much more secure.

You're missing quotes around your string. SQL needs quotes to identify it as a string. Otherwise it uses as a number.

Where you say

```
insert into ... values(12/6)
```

It should be

```
Insert into ... Values '12/6')
```

Try:

```
"INSERT INTO test (folder)
VALUES ('".$folder."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO test (folder)
VALUES (' ".$folder." ' )";
```

Comment: We try to encourage descriptions as well as code. Can you say (in your answer, not the comments please) what the core issue is?

Comment: The author forgot to include `'` signs for string literal. Although I can update the post, I'd like to ask @Sanjaya to do it/